# Trying to understand the Moore–Aronszajn theorem for a specific case

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $k(a,b) = \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}$. Then one can prove that this is a positidive definite, symmetric function on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, hence a "kernel" in the sense of functinal analysis and one can apply the Moore-Aronszajn theorem:

Let $\phi(a): b \mapsto k(a,b)$ and the reproducing kernel Hilbert space is given by ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Moore%E2%80%93Aronszajn_theorem )

$$H = \{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i \phi(x_i) | \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{p \ge 0} \sqrt{\sum_{i=n}^{n+p} a_i^2} = 0\}$$

I want to try to get a feeling for the elements $f \in H$, but for this I need to understand the expression

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{p \ge 0} \sqrt{\sum_{i=n}^{n+p} a_i^2} = 0$$

better. Can you give examples of sequences $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ which

a) satisfy the expression above

b) do not satisfy the expression above

?

Is the last equation equivalent to

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2 < \infty$$
?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The lim sup isn't right according to the Moore-Aronsjan theorem. It should read $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{p \ge 0} \sum_{i = n}^{n+p} a_i \overline{a_j} K(x_i,x_j)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know too much about reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces, so I'll just look at your limit in isolation. As you say, it is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2<\infty$. First, we can get rid of the square root:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{p\ge 0}\sum_{i=n}^{n+p}a_i^2=0
$$
Since we are summing positive terms, the supremum is just a limit, so:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}a_i^2=0
$$
This is just the tails of the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2$, and it is easy to prove that the series converges if and only if the tails go to $0$.

These square-summable sequences are exactly the sequences in [$\ell^2$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space). For example, $\langle \frac1n\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is in $\ell^2$ (i.e. satisfies your condition), while $\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying answer. I was a bit unsure